# getting the StackOverflowError in below piece of java code

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

I am trying to implement the soft delete on a table and below is the code I have done to achieve the same

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I am getting the below exception on debugging

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.test.User.toString()
```

please advise it is related to the impact of Lombok that I am using in the entity.

Comment: lombok `Data` generates `toString` for you and you probably are using bidirectional association in your SubDomain class. And probably SubDomain also has toString method overriden. You are simply getting infinite loop of `toString` calls because of this bidirectional association I guess. Show your `SubDomain` class.

Comment: @michalk is right, I've seen this before. Try excluding `subDomains` from the `toString` generation if posible

Comment: @lealceldeiro Thanks for the quick suggestion request you to please cross check my above table design too especially for the column is_active

Comment: You should probably open another separate post for this other concern of yours (regarding to the impact of lombok in the entity and the database table), but I don't think it would necessary. As far as I know lombok has nothing to do with the persisten layer. All it does is to create a bunch of builders for you (getters, setters, toString, etc). None of those affect the persistent layer. But it is always sane to be meticulous with this and analyze your project taking a big picture of the whole context.

Comment: “below is the code” where ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok `@Data` generates `toString` for you and you are probably using bidirectional association in your `Product` class. And probably `Product` also has `toString` method overriden. You are simply getting infinite loop of `toString` calls because of this bidirectional association I guess.

One solution suggested by lealceldeiro would be to exclude products field in your `User` class from being taken into account for `toString` method generation. You can achieve this by annotating your field with `@ToString.Exclude` lombok annotation :

```
@ToString.Exclude
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or you could exclude the `user` field in your `Product` entity.

You can read about lombok [`@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) on their official site.

Comment: A link to [`@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) may be of help to the OP in case s/he wants to take a detailed reading about this.

Comment: @michalk Thaks yes it works request you to please also cross-check my table design I have edited above

Comment: it is hard to reason about the design without knowing the context. For me it looks ok. However on StackOverflow if one question has been answered, you should not add additional aspects to your question when it is not directly connected to the problem. You should post another question about it.